How to accumulate cell selection in a datagrid when selection mode is full row?
Im making an app for touch screens, I want to make it so when you click on the rows of the grid they will get accumulated and processed later. I have to say I have fullRowSelect instead of CellSelect
So far Im trying for cell click event
But it will not accumulate selected cells. Any idea why?
Thanks in advance !
private void DataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
    {
        dataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
    }
}

Accumulate cell selection

Your code snippet won't do anything because you're clicking on a row that's already selected by then. Use the built-in functions and shortcuts. Ctrl-Key+MouseClick, Shift-Key+Up-Key/Down-Key.

As I said I will be working with touch screens and the use of keyboard won't be available in most cases. What build in function do you refer?

In this case, using a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn makes more sense. No? Anyway, to keep the previous selections: 1) Add a class field of type HashSet<int>. 2) Implement the SelectionChanged event to: A) Add the CurrentRow.Index to the hash set instance if the CurrentRow is not null. B) Loop over the list to select the rows respectively. ex. dgv.Rows[currentForEachIndex].Selected = true;.  Don't do B before A.

Make sure you have Multiple select property set to true (allow multiple select). Then you will have selected rows as datagridviewrow array to process as you desire.
